# How to insert with a foreign key in the child table oophp

Tags: php, mysql

UPDATE : I have two tables **users** And **requests**  users table has columns **id username,password and town** i can insert data in users successfully .requests table has **id ,user_id ,product_name, proposed_price and request_description** ,  where user_id is a foreign key referencing id from users table, the problem is that  insert data fails in requests table which has user_id as a foreign key . **i get nothing in requests table**

**This function is supposed to be used in insertion:**

```
    public function  User_request ($product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description) {

     $qry = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = ? ");
     $qry->bind_param("i", id);
     $result= $qry->execute();
     $user_id = $qry->fetch();
     $qry->close();

    if($user_id > 0){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  requests (user_id, product_name, proposed_price, request_description) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("isss",$user_id, $product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE request_description = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $request_description);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    }
}
```

**And below codes call above function:**

```
       <?php

  include './DbHandler.php';
  $db = new DBHandler();

   // json response array
  $response = array("error" => FALSE);

 if ( isset($_POST['product_name']) && isset($_POST['proposed_price']) &&        isset($_POST['request_description']) ) {

// receiving the post params
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$proposed_price =$_POST['proposed_price'];
$request_description =$_POST['request_description'];

    // create a new request
    $user = $db-User_request($product_name, $proposed_price,    $request_description);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["proposed_price"] = $user["proposed_price"];
        $response["user"]["request_description"] = $user["request_description"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "oops error occured!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
   else {
     $response["error"] = TRUE;
      $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters are missing!";
     echo json_encode($response);
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: The error message?

Comment: Could you add your table structure? Also, which table is "A" and which is "B"?

Comment: If you have a foreign key in requests table pointing to users table through the user_id field, then why don't you populate the user_id field when you insert a record into requests table?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer , table A has : id,username,password and town   Table B : id , user_id, product_name, proposed_price,    request_description

Comment: @Shadow , what i need is to not leave user_id empty , but get its value referring to users id.

Comment: Well, it is your code, find a way to get the current user's id and make it part of the insert statement. Since there is no clue in the code as to how to achieve this, we cannot help you any further.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly, the problem is that you have a `foreign key` pointing to the user issuing the request and when you try to `insert` to that `table`, you get an exception since the `foreign key` is not nullable. There are two possible solutions: you either find the proper user and use its id as `user_id` in the insert statement, or you modify the `foreign key` column to be nullable, so you support user-less requests.

So, the first solution is to:

- pass the `user_id` to `User_request` `function`
- modify `User_request`'s parameter list by adding `$user_id` there
- modify your `insert` statement and add `$user_id` as the fourth parameter

The second solution is to `alter` the `table` so that `user_id` to allow `null`s. I believe you need the first solution.

EDIT:

I believe this line:

```
$user = $db-User_request($product_name, $proposed_price,    $request_description);
```

is

```
$user = $db->User_request($product_name, $proposed_price,    $request_description);
```

Also, you have this value: `$user["username"]`

I am not sure about the name of the user table, but will assume it is called `users` and has an `id` and a `username` field, so a query like:

```
select id, username from users where username = ?
```

would return the relevant data and you could implement a function called `getUserByUsername` which will take a `username`, which will be `$user["username"]` in our case and return the user (note, that this is better read from `$_SESSION`, but I do not know what you have there). From here you can read `user_id` and you will be able to pass it as:

```
//I left the name user here, but you essentially gather a request record
$user = $db->User_request($product_name, $proposed_price,    $request_description, $user_id);
```

and the other `function` would change to:

```
         //I left the name user here, but you essentially gather a request record
         public function  User_request ($product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description, $user_id) {



    //Notice the fourth ? and user_id at the end of the liist
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  requests ( product_name, proposed_price, request_description, user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

    //and you need the effective value as well
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $product_name, $proposed_price, $request_description, $user_id);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM requests WHERE request_description = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $request_description);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to kindly ask the downvoter for the cause of the downvote.

Comment: That is great idea sir ,but exactly what i am longing for is to get primary key id of table A in the field of foreign key(user_id) of table B (requests).

Comment: and i passed user_id to user_request function  . but as user_id is to a text field i get error that required parameters are missing

Comment: i am sorry for they downvote but you were in good way to help me

Comment: @user3518835, I have edited my answer. Hopefully it is more helpful now.

Comment: I can hear you @Lajos  sorry EDIt :  i might change username to product_name

Comment: your help is taking me on the next level of solving this issue of how to insert a value to a foreign key column i have . i post a response when i reach on it soon. and if someone else has a complement can help us

Comment: @user3518835, inserting records with foreign keys are in my daily routine, but I do not know your request parameters, session variables and table structure. If I knew those, I could give you more information.

Comment: ,Wow now i am lucky .may be is my less explanation to .  i have  a table called users which has  these columns  id,username,password and town and another one called requests  as you see it in  User_request  function . requests table has  id , user_id, product_name, proposed_price, request_description  as columns where user_id is a foreign key and references id of users table . and  i want to insert product_name, proposed_price, request_description in requests table with user_id as foreign key . i hope now you get me well

Comment: @user3518835, from here I can understand the relevant part of your DB schema. This means that you need to get users.id by users.username. The value of username should be available somehow, either as a $_GET or a $_POST parameter, or a $_SESSION value. Without the username you will not be able to get users.id. You also need to make sure that the username is authenticated and was written by its owner by having him/her enter a password and checking its validity. If you are able to get that, then you need to pass that parameter to the changed function as in my answer.

Comment: yes  i understand and i am able to pass values in database in users (table) using $_POST ,but what it seems to complicate met is to use this  technic  of yours  in my codes above

Comment: @user3518835, can you update your question with the new code and tell me where does it break and what is the error message?

Comment: i did it , check the update above and see if you can help me .thanks

Comment: @user3518835, ok, I will.

Comment: @user3518835, I checked it, but did not find the update.

Comment: Oops . sorry ,check it now i did it

Comment: @user3518835, now your query looks ok, but I am afraid your input for $user_id is not correct. You have added a query at the start of the function which gathers id by id. This is unnecessary, if you already have the id. If you do not have the id, then it is needed, but you need to query by username, for example. Also, the line of $qry->bind_param("i", id); seems to be invalid. What is the error you get now?

Comment: , is the insertion in requests table failure error i have ,the one i set in the code which calls user_request function .  "oops error occurred!" . **it seems that my way fails, please can you share me source codes or  the link shows me the way you insert with a foreign key please !?**

Comment: @user3518835, do not give up. The foreign key is not a special column which works in a different way from others, except that upon insertion its correctness is automatically checked. So you need to get the correct value instead and use it for your query. This is really nothing special and nothing too difficult. Your problem is that you lack context, therefore I recommend that you should study a tutorial and your pain will be greatly reduced. For example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-foreign-keys.html Here you can see examples of how it is used.

Comment: @user3518835, in the example they are using variables often to read it, but since you are in PHP, you can use a variable. Nothing special, really, just follow a few tutorials, even if you are frustrated. Trust me, I know the feeling, I was a beginner a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos for your encouragements and your help

Comment: @user3518835, you are welcome, take two hours to follow a tutorial and I am sure you will be confident that you can do it. Let me know about the result.